# MS Access - Assign custom number as new record is created

Tags: ms-access

I want to assign a unique number to each record:

last 2 digits of the  current year + a number which increases automatically from 0001 to 9999

I've somehow got it to work with the help of [this thread](https://access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=237156) but I want to generate the number automatically as a new record is created. [This suggestion](https://access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showpost.php?p=1210941&postcount=6) won't work for me.

If you make a new record and click the button it works but not with the before update event. The code behind is the same.

[My working example](https://app.box.com/s/sf1kd7n9ib6bkm6qc9mbzm0pfezvc2pa).

```
'generate custom number when you click the button
Private Sub Comando10_Click()

    If Me.NewRecord Then

        Dim ThisYear As String
        ThisYear = Format(Date, "yy")
        Me.campo = ThisYear & Format(Nz(DMax("Right(campo, 4)", "tabella", "Left(campo,2) = '" & ThisYear & "'"), 0) + 1, "0000")

    End If

End Sub

'generate custom number as a new record is created
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

    If Me.NewRecord Then

        Dim ThisYear As String
        ThisYear = Format(Date, "yy")
        Me.campo = ThisYear & Format(Nz(DMax("Right(campo, 4)", "tabella", "Left(campo,2) = '" & ThisYear & "'"), 0) + 1, "0000")

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: If you button code works, then the before update code will also work. Users will NOT see the new custom ID until they "save" the record (such as moving off the record or closing the form. If you want to see the custom number "right away" as they start typing, then put that above code into the on-insert event - it will then appear RIGHT as they start typing anywhere in the form. So what you have should work, but users will not see it until they "go back" to the record. Are you saying before update don't' work, or that users don't see the results until they go back to the record?

Comment: Ha! That was it. I didn't realize I had to "go back" to the record. I had another "helper" field where I started writing but nothing happened. You helped me understand I just had to close and reopen my form. Thanks!

Comment: If you want you can change your comment to an answer so I can mark it as accepted.